# Matlab : Toolkit functions

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, user-interface

I am using OXlearn toolkit of neural networks in Matlab.

It is a GUI based toolkit, But I want to access the functions which are being called for every operation done on GUI. I've read the manual, but it has no information regarding writing custom scripts for it.

Can someone tell me a way to access functions which are called for every step done on GUI?