# Matlab : Reshaping Matrix to separate matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, formatting, reshape

I have a matrix `Data`. i want to reshape this matrix into `32` matrices of dimension `128x14`.

> > 4096/32

```
ans =

   128
```

> > size(Data)

ans =

```
    4096          14
```

How can i do this by using reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply:

```
out = reshape(data, 128, 14, 32);
```

You will get 32 2D matrices placed into a 3D matrix where each slice is `128 x 14`.  Be aware of how MATLAB will create this matrix.  The elements will be populated in column major order, so it will take columns of your `data` matrix and stack them from left to right until you get 14 columns of 128.  It then moves to the next slice in your 3D matrix and picks up where it left off until we run out of elements.

Comment: thanks man! And yes i am him. Stack blocked me from asking more questions so yea :

Comment: But now if i want to access the 2d matrix from 3d, should i just use (126,14,1)

Comment: Hahaha ok. Do this: `out(:, :, 1)`. This accesses all the rows and columns of the first slice. Change the 1 to whatever slice you want.

Comment: Dude thank you so much. Just last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357139/matlab-toolkit-functions

Comment: Don't know the answer. Sorry.